# Bootstrap dropdown-center not behaving as expected

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am using the latest Bootstrap 5, dropdown-center is not behaving as expected on a dropdown.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<script
  src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/53b1bfb7db.js"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<title>Movie Reviews | Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <head>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">MovieDB</a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbar"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div
        class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between"
        id="navbar"
      >
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown-center">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
              ><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-user fa-2xl"></i
            ></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</head>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
</body>
```

Currently, there seems to be zero difference visually between the dropdown and dropdown-center. I am open to any solutions; I am aware of the old method used to center a dropdown, but I would like to use the newer method where possible in Bootstrap 5

Answer (score 1):

First, if you're using Bootstrap 5, change `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"` to `data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar"`.

Second, `dropdown-center` works, but not inside the `navbar`. Try to place exactly the same code outside the `navbar` and you'll see it works.

See the snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/53b1bfb7db.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Movie Reviews | Home Page</title>
</head>

<body>

  <head>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">MovieDB</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbar">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown-center">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-user fa-2xl"></i></a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 3</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </head>
  <div class="nav-item dropdown-center mt-3">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-user fa-2xl"></i></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <main></main>
  <footer></footer>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

---

**EDIT**

Add the following CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  transform: translateX(50vw);
  margin-left: calc(-75px - 12px) !important;
}
```

You need to set the `width` and `transform` the `.dropdown-menu` by half viewport width (i.e., `50vw`). Try to remove `margin-left` and you'll see what `transform: translateX(50vw);` does. Then center the `.dropdown-menu` by setting `margin-left: calc(-75px - 12px) !important;`. How did I get to these numbers? If you set the `width` to `150px`, half of that is `75px`. Plus, you need to take into account `12px` padding of the `.container`.

See the snippet below.

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  transform: translateX(50vw);
  margin-left: calc(-75px - 12px) !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/53b1bfb7db.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Movie Reviews | Home Page</title>
</head>

<body>

  <head>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">MovieDB</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbar">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown-center">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-user fa-2xl"></i></a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 3</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </head>
  <main></main>
  <footer></footer>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I would suppose I am looking for more of an explanation of what is causing it not to work so I can add the necessary CSS or changes to make it work. It seems to me it is possibly the margin on the container or the position on the dropdown. I have used chromes dev tools extensively and still cannot come up with an explanation.

Comment: I edited my answer. Bootstrap simply has some default styles which you need to change if you want to achieve something custom.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering how to temporarily fix this issue, you have to the following classes to the nav item that holds the dropdown d-flex flex-column align-items-center, you than have to apply an inline style of left: unset !important to the dropdown-menu element.

Below is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/53b1bfb7db.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Movie Reviews | Home Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark mb-3">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarNav"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div
            class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between"
            id="navbarNav"
          >
            <ul class="navbar-nav" id="navbarNav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav" id="navbarNav">
              <li
                class="nav-item dropdown d-flex flex-column align-items-center"
              >
                <a
                  href="#"
                  class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                  data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                  ><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-user fa-2xl"></i> Username</a
                >
                <div class="dropdown-menu" style="left: unset !important">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 1</a>
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 2</a>
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 3</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main></main>
    <footer></footer>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3"crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If there is a reason this happens by default, please comment with an explanation.